# Ionic 3 App - Best way to work with non-ionic html components

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, checkbox, ionic3

Ionic library offers a big collection of components and the documentation is great. So, if you need a button with a custom function called onClick, you quickly find the best way to do it by placing the button into a page.html (home.html in my case)

```
<button ion-button (click)="logEvent(this)"> Button</button>
```

and adding a function to the into a page.ts (home.ts in my case)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

  logEvent(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }
}
```

But what is the best way to work with non-ionic elements such as a standard html checkbox element? Because Ionic 3 does not have a star rating element, I have to import a third-party solution for this element.

The rendering works well and the star rating looks like this
[image]

Now my problem is, I need to bind an onClick function to the inputs of the checkbox element. Having some minor experience in JavaScript, I tend to simply define a script section in the page.html and do some regular JavaScript binding. This, however, does not feel right, and, does not even seem to work.

I would appreciate if someone with experience could point out the most likely obvious way to do it as I could not google it. Obviously I am searching the wrong direction.

The checkbox element looks like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="checkbox" id="st1" value="1" />
  <label for="st1"></label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="st2" value="2" />
  <label for="st2"></label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="st3" value="3" />
  <label for="st3"></label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="st4" value="4" />
  <label for="st4"></label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="st5" value="5" />
  <label for="st5"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/andrucz/ionic2-rating

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend using [**ionic2-rating**](https://github.com/andrucz/ionic2-rating) component. I have used it one of my `Ionic 3 / Angular 5` app and it is working perfectly fine.If you have any issues with it please let me know.

*.html*

```
<rating [(ngModel)]="rate" 
        readOnly="false" <!--default value-->
        max="5" <!--default value-->
        emptyStarIconName="star-outline" <!--default value-->
        halfStarIconName="star-half" <!--default value-->
        starIconName="star" <!--default value-->
        nullable="false" <!--default value-->
        (ngModelChange)="onModelChange($event)"> <!--use it when you need to do something when user clicks on a star. in case you only need to change ngModel property, this property can be ommited.-->
</rating>
```

Comment: Yes, this helped. I still do not understand what to do, if there is no suitable ionic component there and would appreciate if someone would explain it.

Comment: The referenced component helped though. In case, someone has as little experience as me, it is important to understand, that one can import different components into an ionic project using CLI like in the case of the ionic2-rating component. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic2-rating

The instructions on the npm website are self-explanatory

Comment: Do you have any issues with this component?

Comment: It works like a charm. I just still wonder what I would needed to do, in case there would be no suitable component and I would work with a standard customized checkbox.

Comment: You don't need to worry about that. The Ionic community is huge. So you can find out most of the solutions in an ionic way.